# Customizing totals lines in Woocommerce customer email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

My woocommerce sends out an  as it is suppose to.

How ever the tax fields shows up with what seems to be an unclosed tag.

I have grepped thru the entire woocommerce code, but I cant find where the tags are generated.

this is how my tax field looks in the email.

```
 Total:     DKK 0.00 <small class="includes_tax"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This can only be the result of a customization that you have made on order totals, or that your theme or a plugin is making. By default there is no such behavior in Woocommerce. It seems in your case due to a plugin (or some customizations) **that displays the currency symbol as a Code**.

Now order totals rows in Woocommerce email notifications are generated using the `WC_Order` method [**`get_order_item_totals()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html#_get_order_item_totals)

Then you can make changes in it using the following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'customize_order_line_totals', 1000, 3 );
function customize_order_line_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ){
    // Only on emails notifications
    if( ! is_wc_endpoint_url() || ! is_admin() ) {

        // Remove any other html tags from gran total value
        $total_rows['order_total']['value'] = strip_tags( wc_price( $order->get_total() ) );
    }

    return $total_rows;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should solve your problem.

But the best way should be to find out the guilty, instead of patching something wrong done by some customization somewhere.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will use it as a Temp fix for now until I find the culprit.